# output from while read loop using iterative filename/timestamp

Tags: bash, vmware, esxi

I am attempting to create a script that will iteratively run a command against a variable (which is a fully qualified filename) and output the results of that command to  an individually named/timestamped file (to %S accuracy). Im not great with this stuff at all

here is what I do:

```
find /vmfs/volumes/unlistedpathname/unlistedfoldername |
while read list;do
    vmkfstools -D "$list" >> duringmigration_10mins_"$list".$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S");
done
```

the output im hoping for is something like

```
duringmigration_10mins_blahblahblah.vmx.2016.09.25.21.26.35
```

of course it doesnt work, and im not exactly sure how to solve it. I know the problem outright is $list as the filename variable will reprint the fullpath, so I need some sort of way to tell the loop "hey just use the filename as the variable NOT the full path" but im not sure how to do that in this case. Im also hoping to be able to run this from any location not specific path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems preventing the behaviour you are looking for:

1. As you saw the filenames returned by find include the full path.
2. Your find command will return all the files *and* the directory name.

We solve #1 by calling `basename` on `$list` in the output filename.

We solve #2 by adding `-type f` to the find command to only return files and not directories.

```
find /vmfs/volumes/unlistedpathname/unlistedfoldername -type f |
while read list ; do
    vmkfstools -D "${list}" >> "duringmigration_10mins_$(basename "${list}").$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S")"
done
```

Comment: brilliant, elegant !  precisely what I needed